# error "Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code -

```
private List<LanguageResource> GetAll()
    {
        return ((Language[])Enum.GetValues(typeof (Language)))
                                .Select(l => new LanguageResource
                                                {
                                                    Id = (int) l,
                                                    Name = l.ToString()
                                                })
                                .OrderBy(l => l.Name)
                                .ToList();
    }
```

Language Class -

```
public class Language : IEmbeddedDocument, IEquatable<Language>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Language()
    {
    }

    private Language(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public static Language Unknown      { get { return new Language(0, "Unknown"); } }
    public static Language English      { get { return new Language(1, "English"); } }
    public static Language French       { get { return new Language(2, "French"); } }
    public static Language Spanish      { get { return new Language(3, "Spanish"); } }

}
```

I am getting an error

```
"Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType"
```

The usual fix I find is to cast the return, which I am doing `(Language[])` however I am still getting this error.. How else can I fix this function?

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` needs an enum, `Language` isn't an enum? I'd suggest you [read up on what an `enum` is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: This seems like you are trying to make your own `enum` implementation without using any enums. Very bizarre.

Comment: Read Jimmy Bogard's article on enum classes: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined an `enum`. You have defined a custom class that has some static properties that make it *look like* an `enum` by defining `Language.English`, for example.

To do what I think you want (enumerate all pre-defined `Language`s), you'll need to get all static properties of type `Language` using reflection instead of calling `Enum.GetValues`

Something like (untested)

```
typeof(Language).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(f => f.PropertyType == typeof(Language))
```

Comment: @DavidG Thanks - I've always seen them as fields so I missed that they were properties.